# How do you make a range in Rust?

Tags: loops, for-loop, range, rust

The documentation doesn't say how and the tutorial completely ignores for loops.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In rust, what is the idiomatic equivalent of Haskell's \[n..m\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836096/in-rust-what-is-the-idiomatic-equivalent-of-haskells-n-m)

Comment: Take a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html

Comment: This is an old and obsolete question, but you should have provided at least the link to the "tutorial" you were reading. We cannot just guess.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of 1.0, *for* loops work with values of types with the [`Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

The book describes this technique in [chapter 3.5](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#looping-through-a-collection-with-for) and [chapter 13.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/ch13-02-iterators.html).

If you are interested in how *for* loops operate, see the described syntactic sugar in *[Module std::iter](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html)*.

Example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let strs = ["red", "green", "blue"];

    for sptr in strs.iter() {
        println!("{}", sptr);
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fa59e1122bce8a15eb3f859c19ce53b1))

If you just want to iterate over a range of numbers, as in C's *for* loops, you can create a numeric range with the `a..b` syntax:

```rust
for i in 0..3 {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

If you need both, the index and the element from an array, the idiomatic way to get that is with the [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) method:

```rust
fn main() {
    let strs = ["red", "green", "blue"];

    for (i, s) in strs.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("String #{} is {}", i, s);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The loop items are borrowed references to the iteratee elements.  In this case, the elements of `strs` have type `&'static str` - they are borrowed pointers to static strings.  This means `sptr` has type `&&'static str`, so we dereference it as `*sptr`.  An alternative form which I prefer is:

  ```
    for &s in strs.iter() {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
  ```

Comment: How to make rev for 0..3?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov Add parenthesis:
`for i in (0..3).rev() { // Code here... }`
Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html

Comment: How do I make `i` a `u8`? I did `for i: u8 in 0..26 {` and it is not working.

Comment: Why is this not the top answer, despite being the most voted and the accepted answer? SO works in weird ways..

Comment: @wheeler `for i in 0u8..26u8` (one of the `u8`s can even be omitted, but that may be confusing for beginners)

Answer (score 12):

`for i in range(0, 100)` is now deprecated in favour of `for i in 0..100` (according to `rustc 1.0.0-nightly`.

Also worth noting is the compiler can't disambiguate when you use an identifier in the range (e.g., `for i in 0..a`), so you have to use `for i in (0..a)`, but there's [a pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/20958) submitted to fix this.

Comment: identifier ambiguity has been fixed in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21374

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the [Loops](http://doc.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#loops) section of the tutorial does cover `for` loops:

> When iterating over a vector, use `for` instead.
>
> ```
> for elt in ["red", "green", "blue"] {
>    std::io::println(elt);
> }
> ```

But if you needed indices, you could do something like the following, using the [`uint::range` function from the core library](http://doc.rust-lang.org/doc/core/files/uint-rs.html#uint.range) (or `int::range` or `u8::range` or `u32::range` or `u64::range`) and Rust's syntax for blocks:

```
range(0u, 64u, {|i| C[i] = A[i] + B[i]});
```

Rust used to support this equivalent syntax but it was later removed:

```
range(0u, 64u) {|i|
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious why Rust has two different syntaxes for function definitions and blocks. Seems like they could save the coder trouble by reusing `fn(args...)` instead of `|args|`.

Comment: @mcandre Actually, the Ruby-style block syntax `{|args| body}` is used to denote a closure rather than just a function. It's also really convenient for simplifying usage of anonymous functions as you might see them used in Javascript, since any function that accepts a closure as its last argument (such as a callback) can be written _after_ the function call, as in Lindsey's third example above. Finally, even though Rust has a few different types of closures, Rust can infer the type of closure you want when using the block syntax. See also http://doc.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#closures

Comment: Does this still work? I can't get range(n,n) {|i| ...} to compile. I get weird errors.

Comment: As of rust 0.6, for int::range() |i| { C[i] = A[i] + B[i]; }  should work.  for is syntactic sugar which passes the closure in as an argument, iirc.

Answer (score 6):

```rust
let range = (start..end).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

Comment: Do you know why the decision was made to support `FromIterator<usize>` for `Vec<i32>` but not `Vec<i64>`? Would love to use this syntax but `i64` is so common...

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of rustc 0.4 (Oct 2012), the alternate construction of

```
range(0u, 64u) {|i|
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

appears to not be supported any more.

Answer (score -4):

Use [int::range](http://doc.rust-lang.org/doc/core/files/int-rs.html#int.range).

Comment: if there was an int type, it has been deprecated now.

Comment: He's right. It has been removed so this answer is obsolete.