# In Rust, what is the idiomatic equivalent of Haskell's [n..m]?

Tags: rust

How do I produce a list containing all the integers in Rust? I'm looking for the equivalent of Haskell's `[n..m]` or Python's `range(n, m+1)` but can't find anything.

I'm aware of the `int::range` function and thought it was what I was looking for, but it is made to iterate over a range, not to produce it.

Comment: Be aware that because of Haskell's lazy evaluation, its list type in fact consists of an element and a function to continue producing the rest of the list (i.e., the next element and the *next* function, and so on), which means that in many ways Rust's `Iterator` types are in fact semantically a closer match for Haskell's `[a]` than `Vec<T>` is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Note** that this answer pertains to a pre-1.0 version of Rust and does not apply for 1.0. Specifically, `std::iter::range` and `std::iter::range_inclusive` were removed.

As of Rust 1.0.0-alpha, the easiest way to accomplish this is to use the convenience functions provided in the module [`std::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/iter/index.html): [`range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/iter/fn.range.html) and [`range_inclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/iter/fn.range_inclusive.html), which return iterators generating a list of numbers in the range [low, high) or [low, high], respectively.

In addition, you can build a vector from an iterator using the [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.collect) method:

```
use std::iter::range_inclusive;
let first_hundred: Vec<i32> = range_inclusive(1, 100).collect();
println!("upper bound inclusive: {:?}, exclusive: {:?}",
         first_hundred,
         range(101, 201).collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

Note that the return value of `collect` has its type explicitly specified in both its uses above. Normally, the Rust compiler can infer the types of expressions without an explicit specification, but `collect` is one of the most common cases for which the type cannot be fully inferred, in this case because it can't infer a concrete type that implements the trait `FromIterator<A>`, the return type of `collect`.

The type of a generic return value can be specified either as an explicit type in a `let` definition statement or inline by using the `function::<Type>()` syntax. Since inference fails only due to not knowing a concrete type implementing `FromIterator<A>`, it's possible, when explicitly specifying a generic type, to leave "holes" for type arguments which will be inferred, signified by `_`. This is done with the second call to `collect` above—in the expression `Vec<_>`, it's explicitly specified that the container receiving elements from `collect` is a `Vec<T>`, but the compiler figures out what exact type `T` must be. Currently, integers whose types are left unspecified and can't be inferred fall back to `i32` (32-bit machine integer) as a default.

Answer (score 17):

It is now possible to use `..=` in Rust:

```
let vec: Vec<_> = (n ..= m).collect();
```

gives you a `Vec` from all the numbers from `n` to `m`.

`..=` is the inclusive range operator, whereas `..` is exclusive.

Comment: *to `m` inclusive* — pedantically, it's not truly inclusive. For example, there's no easy way to get all `u8` values from 0 to 255. There are various RFCs floating around that propose to add an inclusive range operator.

Comment: This also can be write as `let vec = Vec::from_iter(n .. m + 1)`.

Answer (score 10):

> **Note** that this answer pertains to a pre-1.0 version of Rust and does not apply for 1.0. Specifically, `Vec::from_fn` was removed.

There's probably nothing really idiomatic as of now. There is a handful of convenience functions to construct vectors, for example you can use [`Vec::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_fn):

```
Vec::from_fn(m+1-n, |i| i+n)
```

Comment: You'll find Counter a little more idiomatic. http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/std/iterator.html#struct-counter

Answer (score 7):

Since Rust 1.26.0 you can use the [`RangeToInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeToInclusive.html) (`..=`) operator to generate an inclusive range.

```
let v: Vec<_> = (n..=m).collect()
```